# Why ajax request treated as form submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Although I am sending a request using Ajax, the response from the server has a full HTML page instead of expected simple JOSN object.

My sending code:

```
<script>
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("name", "dasdf");
        form.append("email", "admin@admin.com");
        form.append("mobile_number", "454545");
        form.append("pin", "1234");
        form.append("gender", "male");
        form.append("allow_users_see_me", "true");
        form.append("password", "123456");
        form.append("country_code", "QA");

        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "http://localhost/register",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "X-CSRF-Token": "2oVPtMysQ30esIv6X2LJYghonCAbR4Zt4Op20SEV",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "postman-token": "b3c3ff77-a12f-7b60-4b53-16fcbcb97469"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "data": form
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    </script>
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    Log::info('start');
}
```

**EDIT**

I found the place where the laravel return the exception, it's inside the render function.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        } elseif ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            $e = new HttpException(403, $e->getMessage());
        } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException && $e->getResponse()) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        }

        if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
            return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->renderHttpException($e), $e);
        } else {
            return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
        }
    }
```

And laravel return HttpException.

**-UPDATE-**

This is my route

```
Route::get('test', 'loginController@test');
```

and this is the error

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    The name field is required.<br/>
                    The email field is required.<br/>
                    The mobile number field is required.<br/>
                    The pin field is required.<br/>
                    The gender field is required.<br/>
                    The password field is required.<br/>
            </div>
```

**-EDIT-**
The route is:

Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');

Comment: The format you send the request in has no bearing on what the format of the response is. Have you checked the response itself? Normally HTML instead of a JSON response indicates a 404 or 500 error on the server

Comment: Can you post up the PHP/controller code that is providing the response please and the route its linked to. Something I've found through experience is that I will get HTML in response to an ajax call when there's an error. Your best bet is to do some finer debugging and see where that takes you.

Comment: As Laravel will validate the $request rules before executing the function, the Log above will not log the 'start'.. I am sending you the function signature and the Log command that was not executed

Comment: You need to figure out which rule its not getting by then. Try running the request through chrome like this: open up web developer tools `f12` on windows/`Cmd + Opt + I` on mac, click on the network tab, run the request which produces the error, click on the new request that shows up in the network tab (you should also see the error status code too) and hit preview - what do you see?

Comment: Just realised you said "And laravel return HttpException." Well there's your starting point, as I said before "Can you post up the PHP/controller code that is providing the response please and the route its linked to." So where's the route? Something is probably going wrong there I am guessing?

Comment: I checked the network tab and it's return `status code 200` ,and this is the route `http://localhost/register`

Comment: Okay cool. Can you: 1. Please post the full route in your question, I want to see if it's for `post` or not, 2. go to the network tab for the request and go to preview - you should get a web browser view of the html code, what is the full error details - please add them to your question. Thanks!

Comment: I meant the `register` one the ajax call is hitting, not `Route::get('test', 'loginController@test');`. Your response looks like your `RegisterRequest` is validating, isn't that what you want to happen? You can inspect the outgoing post request when your run it and see what attributes are missing, clearly your `form.append("name", "dasdf");` etc. don't appear to be working.

Comment: Then how to send it properly?

Comment: See my answer, hope it's clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

After the comments we exchanged, ***I assume*** your `form` variable is either not getting set up properly and PHP isn't able to read the data. It may be worth debugging the form variable before sending it off and seeing **why** it isn't being read properly. In theory it should be okay but I'm guessing something is going wrong that you didn't intend if you're getting `The name field is required.` etc.

Usually if I have all my fields in a form and I'm using jQuery I would just do this:

```
var form = $("form").serialize(); // or pass the id or other selector
```

Try `console.log`ing the variable after to see how the data structure is different to the way you're doing it now.